# In java, What is the proper/canonical way to access a class and it’s methods at runtime by a unique trait (fully qualified name/ID/) at runetime

Tags: java

I can’t find any way to do it besides reflection requiring a hard coded arrays of every object, of which there will be hundreds. That just seems like bad design. Is there a proper way to call the constructor/static methods for a class by its fully qualified name or, ideally, a unique attribute like its ID or name. I was assume so since this would be needed often in video game. For example, to spawn in an item with an ID of 5.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why "besides reflection"? What you are describing is basically that.

Comment: All the methods I’ve seen with reflection involve reflecting an object that already exists. I don’t want to maintain hard coded arrays of hundreds of objects that need constantly updated. It would have much faster access though

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's obviously not possible to call a method on an object _that doesn't even exist_. Your question right now is way too abstract that it is unclear what you are asking about. I suggest that you give concrete examples of what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Say I’m coding a Pokémon game and I want to spawn in a pikachu for the player to battle. How would I create a pikachu object by its ID (25) without having to have an array of every Pokémon? If I wanted to use quick attack, how would I call the move’s static use() method without having to have an array of every move?

Comment: Don’t constructors by definition work on objects that don’t exist?

Comment: So you have a `QuickAttack` class that has a `use` method? You should really rethink your design. The data about Pokemons and Moves sound like they should all be stored in some sort of data file, rather than in code. You read that file into a dictionary/array/whatever. Why should different moves and Pokemons be different classes? Also, [recommended reading](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/),

Comment: It makes sense to do that with Pokémon, though it seems like it would be very slow to read from disk. But doing that with moves would require making a scripting language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the essense of the question—there's a difference between creating *instances* of objects and different object types themselves. For example, there  are object types such as `String`, but there can be *many* different instances of `String`. For example,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   String newString = "foo" + i;
}
```

This is 3 lines of code but created 1000 String instances.

In games and in most large scale applications, you can have hundreds, thousands, perhaps millions of *instances* of a handful of different *types* of objects.

You may, for example, want to have an Enemy object type. You would create an Enemy class, and that class could have a property, such as `name`.

Then you could easily create objects dynamically during your program, something like:

```java
class Enemy {
   
    public String name;
    
    public Enemy(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

void spawnNewEnemy() {
   return new Enemy("some unique name");
}
```

And this could be called hundreds of times in your program in different conditions, and you can have hundreds or thousands of `Enemy` *instances*, but only would define one class, `Enemy`. You could have a configuration text file that defines the different names of enemies and their IDs, damage, etc. and then just have the program on startup read that text file and construct `Enemy` objects based on these properties.

Creating object instances like these is what object-oriented programming is all about. Your code responds to different inputs from the user or external sources, and in return, creates and modifies objects.

You should really only have different classes, though, for things that are inherently different in functionality.

Comment: I’m using inheritance from the main class. All the functions are defined in the main class and overridden if necessary in the subclass functions. Each subclass also has unique base stats, move pools, etc. It seams very inefficient to read these from disk whenever making an object, which as you said can happen millions of times. Are modern computers so fast the read time would be trivial regardless of whether it’s disk or memory?

Comment: I’m hoping to have about 1000 threads on a raspberry pi type computer. Can reading potentially hundreds of files per second be accomplished? Am I overoptimising?

Comment: Configuration should definitely be something that gets loaded in on startup and can exist as its own class(es) (like a configuration object). No need to read from the file more than once. So you instantiate the configuration object(s) at the beginning and read data from it as you go. You can store data in a Map or similar structure, which would provide extremely fast lookup times.

Comment: A framework like Spring could help with configuration management. But in essence, you shouldn’t need too many different subclasses unless they literally define a different type of data. If there end up being hundreds of subclasses of one superclass, it’s likely best to rethink the design. Even the massive Java library has no more than a few subclasses for a given type. If you think about it akin to a database, each table is like a different type of object, and each row is an instance of that type. There will be millions of database rows (instances) with only a handful of tables (object types).

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help guys!

Comment: How would I go about dealing with unique cases, especially the moves? I can’t think of anything but building a scripting language

Comment: You’re welcome! If this answers your question to your satisfaction, please hit the “check” to mark this question as answered. Feel free to open a new question with more details on your new question and link it here.

Comment: For future reference, the answer to my question was the class loader class.